# <Android/Java> Why does different initialization location break the code?

Tags: java, android

I spent the past couple of hours stuck in this problem as can be seen by my post history. Unfortunately, no one could help me with this problem. The solution is as simple as changing the location of the initialization for some reason. TBH I was lucky for it to work for me as I was just trying it out without actually knowing what is happening in the background. Can someone tell me why the first code works while the second one doesn't just because of the initialization location. Shouldn't the streams be initialized and not null since it is done in the constructor?

Working code:

```
private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
private URL url;
private InputStream inputStream;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
private OutputStream outputStream;

public Connection(String login_url) throws IOException {

    url = new URL(login_url);
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

}

public void write(String post_data) throws IOException {
    outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
    bufferedWriter.flush();
}

public String read() throws IOException {
    inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
    String result="", line;

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        result += line;
    }

    return result;
}

public void close() throws IOException {
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Not working code:

```
private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
private URL url;
private InputStream inputStream;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
private OutputStream outputStream;

public Connection(String login_url) throws IOException {

    url = new URL(login_url);
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

    outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

}

public void write(String post_data) throws IOException {

    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
    bufferedWriter.flush();
}

public String read() throws IOException {

    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
    String result="", line;

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        result += line;
    }

    return result;
}
public void close() throws IOException {
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
```

Usage:

```
public class LoginBackground extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
protected Context context;
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
private String login_url = "http://192.168.1.195/login.php";

public LoginBackground(Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}

@Override

protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        try{
            String user = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            Connection conn = new Connection(login_url);

            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user,"UTF-8")+
                    "&"+URLEncoder.encode("pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");

            conn.write(post_data);

            String result = conn.read();

            conn.close();

            return result;

        } catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    if(result.equals("Login successful")){
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
    else{
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}
```

Error starting from where the write function is executed:

```
11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err: java.io.IOException: closed

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:196)

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)

11-06 21:40:06.895 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at com.example.kaiss.socialmedia.Connection.write(Connection.java:52)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at com.example.kaiss.socialmedia.LoginBackground.doInBackground(LoginBackground.java:46)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at com.example.kaiss.socialmedia.LoginBackground.doInBackground(LoginBackground.java:24)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31682/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

11-06 21:40:06.896 31092-31092/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

11-06 21:40:06.897 31092-31092/com.example.kaiss.socialmedia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.kaiss.socialmedia, PID: 31092
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.kaiss.socialmedia.LoginBackground.onPostExecute(LoginBackground.java:71)
                                                                                   at com.example.kaiss.socialmedia.LoginBackground.onPostExecute(LoginBackground.java:24)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: What is the error?  Post some code showing how the objects are used.  And how are those streams, readers, and writers closed?

Comment: @AndrewS done..

Comment: Just a guess - calling `httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()` is preparing to read a response so it's possible the implementation is trying to be as efficient as possible and closes the outputStream under the assumption the write step (the POST) is already complete.  Try finding the source code for the concrete `HttpUrlConnection` implementation and see what the `getInputStream()' code.